# Open saveas dialog box for another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, save-as

I am currently working on a temporary solution but run into a problem....

The situation is:

I have a converter built in Excel, that opens up a XLS File, does some tinkering so the file can be uploaded to an Oracle Database.

The problem is, the XLS file I opened I cannot get the Saveas Dialog box to that file, it always saves a copy of the converter instead.

What I need to happen is to open the Saveas Dialog box in a filepath set the file filter for CSV, for the file that i have opened.

RRBOOK.Activate ***The RR Book is the DIM'd file i opened***

```
Dim FileName As String
FileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("\\FILEPATH\", FileFilter:="CSV (Comma delimited) (*.csv), *.csv")
If FileName <> "False" Then
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName
End If
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `ActiveWorkbook` and `.Activate`.

Instead directly save the desired workbook by

```
RRBOOK.SaveAs FileName
```

Also you should specify the file format you wish to save in according to [XlFileFormat enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat) and [Workbook.SaveAs method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas).

So for saving as CSV you should eg use

```
RRBOOK.SaveAs FileName, xlCSV
```

---

So you would end up with something like

```
Dim FileName As Variant
FileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("\\FILEPATH\", FileFilter:="CSV (Comma delimited) (*.csv), *.csv")
If VarType(FileName) = vbBoolean And FileName = False Then
    'user pressed cancel
    Exit Sub
Else
    RRBOOK.SaveAs FileName
End If
```